One-one mapping need not be invertible
So I was reading a book on abstract algebra. There was a definition there:
$\text{If $S$ is nonempty set, then $A(S)$ is the set of all one-one mappings of $S$ onto itself.}$
The author then gives the following lemma:
$$\sigma\in A(S)\implies\exists\;\sigma^{-1}\in A(S)$$ $$\text{such that }\sigma\circ\sigma^{-1}=\sigma^{-1}\circ\sigma=\operatorname{id}_S\tag{1}$$ where $\operatorname{id}_S:S\to S$ is the identity mapping. This is the point where I am having confusion.  Clearly the lemma is false if we take $S=\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$ and $\sigma(x):= \sin x$ as $\sin$ is one-one in $S$ but not onto, so there doesn't exists any $\sigma^{-1}\in A(S)$ for which $(1)$ holds. What am I missing here?

Well, $\sigma=\sin$ is just not an element of $A(S)$. It may be one-to-one on this domain $S$, but it is not onto - as you mention yourself - so by definition of $A(S)$ ("... mappings of $S$ onto itself") $\sigma\notin A(S)$.
By the way, 'better' notation for this might be $\mathrm{Aut}(S)$ or $\mathrm{Sym}(S)$, and I think it's good to get used to the language of bijections, injections and surjections; $A(S)$ is, imo, better described as the set of bijective functions $S\to S$.

Oh I thought the author meant "... mappings of $S$ onto itself" by that of a mapping $\sigma : S\to S$

@Engineer: If you wish to talk about general, not necessarily surjective, mappings $\sigma: S\to S$, then the standard phrasing is "...mappings of $S$ into itself".
